# Cannot connect to Internet but Ethernet is connected

Tags: networking, 14.04, kubuntu, ethernet

Due to the retirement of Windows XP, I decided to try Kubuntu. I installed it on a Lenovo T61 laptop alongside XP. The Ethernet Controller is Intel Corp 82566Mm Gigabit Network Connection.

The install went smoothly. It's connected with a "wired' Ethernet on `eth0`, which shows connected.

- The browser cannot find any webpages, server not found. I tried to
  `ping google.com`, returned `unknown host`
- I accessed the "Driver Management' but its empty.
- I've changed the DNS servers to `8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`, and `automatic (only addresses)`.
- Under Active Connections, some Kb have been both received and sent.

I am entirely new to Linux.

Please help, as I'd really like to use Linux on other computers as well.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Do you mean 14.04? Also, to bypass possible DNS problems, try pinging `8.8.8.8` directly.

Comment: Yes, I meant 14.04. Tried pinging 8.8.8.8 directly. 100% packet loss: Destination Net Unreachable

Comment: What is the output if `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a nameserver option to the following file:

/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Restart the networking service with:

```
$ sudo service networking restart
```

or reboot the computer to restart the networking service

Comment: I don't think this will ever have any effect. OP mentioned that even directly pinging 8.8.8.8 did not work, so do you think DNS will work?

Comment: He did mention a direct pinging of 8.8.8.8 in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464240/cannot-connect-to-internet-but-ethernet-is-connected/467814?noredirect=1#comment612629_464240).

Comment: Note: my above comment was in response to another comment, which is now removed most probably because the commenter was proven wrong.